# Jet EntityFramework Provider reporting 'Could not find installable ISAM.'

Tags: jet-ef-provider

I am using the JetEntityFrameworkProvider

I am trying to connect to an MS Access file (it has extension .sep but it is indeed an access file). I know JetEntityFrameworkProvider does support DB first but I should be able to manually create the models that I need. (Correct ?)

I am trying to define the connection string and provider in code, but it is not working. When I run it I receive the following error

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find installable ISAM.'

Context Class

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    private DbConnection con = new JetConnection();

    public ProjectContext() : base(new JetConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = 'C:\Test-Project.sep'; providerName = JetEntityFrameworkProvider; User Id = Admin; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = SEEME;""), true)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }

}
```

Entity Class

```
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Counter")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know this existed! I'll try it out next week and see if I come up with anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `providerName = JetEntityFrameworkProvider;` from the connection string and try again with just this:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = 'C:\Test-Project.sep'; User Id = Admin; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = SEEME;"`